# Convert string format to date format

Tags: vb.net

How can I convert this string format

> 03.07.2019

to the following Date Format?

> 2019-07-03

This is how the String format I get from Soap Services looks like

[image]

```
Public Class ContractBill
Public StartDate As Date
End Class
Dim ctrBill As New ContractBill With {
    .StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(BillingData.START_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
}
```

this is my attempt to convert the code to the desired format, but with this .StartDate I get the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: "The object of type" System.String "cannot be converted to type" System.IFormatProvider "."

How can I get this Date format yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: Now 07 or 27? Anyways: `Date.ParseExact("03.07.2019", "MM.dd.yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks for the help, I corrected my question, based on your code, am I getting this error? what can i do? System.FormatException: "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in Calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."

Comment: Remove the `ToString(...)` if you want to return a `Date` type.

Comment: with this code I get this format "03.07.2019 00:00:00", that's not what I want ..
.StartDate = Date.ParseExact(BillingData.START_DATE, "dd.MM.yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),

Comment: @Michael A `Date` doesn't have a format. A `String` does. You either want a [non-formatted] `Date` value (which can be formatted later) or a formatted `String` value. Pick one. Your `ContractBill` class obviously currently requires a `Date`, so you should remove the `ToString()` call as JQSOFT suggested and then do the formatting later _when you actually display the value_ (that part of the code you didn't show).

Comment: Exactly, Thank you @AhmedAbdelhameed and according to your edit, then it should be `Date.ParseExact("03.07.2019", "dd.MM.yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` Now you have a valid date, if you want to display it in a DateTimePicker for example, then you need to set the `dtp.Format = Custom` and the `dtp.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"`. I didn't downvote by the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no format for date with **.**, so you have to first replace the **.** with **-** or **/** so you can parse your date into available formats.

```
string date = "03.07.2019";
DateTime value = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Replace(".", "-"));
```

**VB.net**

```
Dim date As String = "03.07.2019"
Dim value As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Replace(".", "-"))
```

Comment: Some cultures do use `.` as separator. Also `. ` (a dot with a space). This is the reason why there's a `CultureInfo` overload. That's not the way to do it, anyway.

Comment: @Jimi well, you say so but that way he will achieve what he is looking for.

Comment: No, it doesn't achieve that either. The class shown expects a Date object, you're providing a string. You won't achieve anything good trying to hammer something into some shape that *looks alike*. + I'm not the one that *say so*. These are culture specific formats that are internationally codified. The .Net classes reflect these formats. I'm just reporting the fact.

Comment: I have done minor changes, have a look now. Output is in DateTime.

Comment: See the comments on the question. That's how you do it (you cannot replace *strings* in a DateTime object). You should use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`, by the way.

Comment: @JQSOFT  Not a *fight*, just a discussion. I won't post another answer that looks like a copy/paste of what's in the *manual* about `TryParseExact`. If this question (already seen a gazillion times) doesn't get an appropriate answer, I'll vote to close & delete or mark as duplicate (which should be its *natural* outcome).

Comment: @Jimi Whatever you say mate. Still can't help in that vote. Still minor :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) method since you know the format of the incoming date:

```
Dim enUS As New CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim inbound As String = "03.07.2019"
Dim outbound As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact(inbound, "MM.dd.yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, outbound) Then
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is formated from: {1}", outbound.ToString("yyyy/dd/MM"), inbound)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", inbound)
End If
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2m8sgV)